# second request is not running as many times as first request when ifcontroller is used

Tags: tomcat, jmeter

I am using jmeter to send two http requests one for login page of my web application and second one to another page after successful login. i added ifcontroller element to which the second http request is added. When i am testing the test plan with 100 requests with rampup period below 10sec i am seeing 100 requests are being fired to the web application w.r.t first request but only 75 requests are being fired w.r.t the second request, in the aggregate report panel. the second request count is not same always, it is changing every time but i never got the count as 100 as for the first request. when i increased the rampup period to 10 sec then only i could see both first and second request counts as 100. does it mean that jmeter client is unable to initiate enough no of threads for the second request.

i am using 4gb ram with 4core machine. will the situation improve if i add more ram to my pc because in the above case i am able to send only 10 requests in 1 sec period, i want to send more number of requests in one sec period.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on If Controller's condition it might be the situation when 2nd request is relies on 1st request success, i.e. if you use [${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) variable as a condition 2nd sampler will fire only if 1st sampler is successful so if login is failed - you won't see 2nd request. See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) for more details.

Regarding throughput, given you follow few simple steps, to wit:

- Run JMeter in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- Disable all listeners
- Use Assertions, Pre/Post Processors, Timers wisely and efficiently

It should be possible to simulate hundredds of concurrent threads from 4 core / 4Gb RAM machine. Just make sure you provide enough threads (virtual users) and iterations.

Comment: Thank you, i shall check this. In the meanwhile, i am using (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==true) && (${__property(ThreadValue,,)} == ${__threadNum}) condition in ifController with Evaluate for All option checked. Interpret condition as Variable expression option is unchecked. And in the BSFPostProcessor node attached to login page, the script is written as ${__setProperty(ThreadValue,${__threadNum},)}. Hope this is fine.

Comment: I think the problem is solved. What i observed is when i removed the second condition in the ifController element i.e., (${__property(ThreadValue,,)} == ${__threadNum}) and the script written in BSF PostProcessor, I am able to send more than 100 requests in one sec time. My guess is, the second condition is causing single thread to send both the requests in a synchronized manner. Thatswhy, it is taking more time to send 100 requests. Anyhow, the first condition in ifController ensures that second request will be sent only when the first request is successful.